# How to change or hide the author meta tag? Facebook still shows the author meta when sharing

Tags: joomla-3.x, facebook, global-configuration, metadata

I am trying to change the author meta tag. Now, when a user goes to share something to facebook, then the author meta tag is displayed his name. I want to change it to his username.

thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Username is used for login - it's the half info required for someone to login into the website. Therefore, it is not a wise idea to reveal such sensitive data to the public.

There is always the author alias field that can be used on a per article basis, to override the author name. See screenshot below:

[image]

Alternatively, you could just change the name of the author-user to a nickname desired for signing the articles, but anyhow avoid publishing the login username.

As a last note, keep in mind that you can totally hide the meta-author tag, from the global configuration settings.

#### Update for the comment:

> I need it for the use of facebook share, because it is generating the
> name of the author and i do not want this. and it is difficult for
> every article to change the author name to a nickname. So in global
> configuration i disable the meta-author tag but the name is still
> displayed in the preview facebook share.

#### Answer:

As for why FB still publishes the author, after changing the Global Configuration settings, it can be cached data.
Apart of "local" Joomla cache, FB scrapper also caches the content of a page, and it won't show any changes in the meta in less than 24 hours.

You can review how FB sees your page at the FB scrapper debug tool:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Also this Q/A might be helpful regarding Facebook: [Facebook Share - Remove: "The Joomla! content management system lets you create webpages..."](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/5467/facebook-share-remove-the-joomla-content-management-system-lets-you-create)

But first you want to make sure that you have actually removed the author metatag from your pages.
Although disabled from the global configuration, a 3rd party SEF extension, or an extension to generate the FB og:meta, might still keep injecting the author-meta in the head of the html of your page.

Checking the head of the html page in the source code of your page with your browser's inspector will help you see, if the following metas have been removed:

```
<meta name="author" content="authorname">
<meta property="article:author" content="authorname">
```

Comment: Lodder thanks for the screenshot addition.

Comment: Was in the process of writing up my answer which was the same so thought I'd donate the screeny to you :)

Comment: @FFrewin thanks for the information. i need it for the use of facebook share, because it is generating the name of the author and i do not want this. and it is difficult for every article to change the author name to a nickname. so i global configuration i disable the meta-author tag but the name is still displayed in the preview facebook share..

Comment: @giorgionasis:: It can be cached data. Also it can happen due to 3rd party SEF extension, or an extension to generate the FB og:meta, that is still injecting an author-meta.

Comment: @giorgionasis:: Check updated answer for more info

Comment: @Lodder:: I managed somehow to remove the image - is it easy to put it back ?

Comment: @FFrewin - done ;)

Comment: @FFrewin thank you very much. i inspect the source code and there is not the mentioned tags. if i share the article in facebook i still watch in preview the author but as you said maybe it is a cache problem from facebook. also this link is very helpful to see what facebook "sees" in the webpage. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ unfortunately, the author name is not listed in the facebook.`s meta tags but it is still displayed in my facebook share :/

Comment: this question might be a bit redundant, but have you tried deleting the original shared item and then resharing after forcing Facebook to rescrape your page?

Comment: @giorgionasis:: if your problem persists, a link to your website would help us tell you more. If your problem is solved, then consider accept the answer.

Comment: @FFrewin sorry for but i had checked and the author name WAS still there. i just checked again and it seems that 24 hour had to be passed before the item has benn "uncached" from facebook. So now the author is not displayed anymore. Just for information if you know: the very first time i go to share, the preview has no image, the second time and after that the image of the item is normally displayed. any idea?thank you